# 'Unresolved reference 'print'' When Using Python 3 on PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I just started coding with Python 3 on Pycharm and whenever I use print, there's a red underline that says `"Unresolved reference 'print'"`. The code runs perfectly, but this is still very annoying to see on the screen.

[image: Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxuMV.png]

I clicked File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart, but it didn't help.